# best chat server for messaging like facebook and whatsapp

Tags: socket.io, chat, ejabberd, livechat

I want to choose the best technology for chat like facebook and whatsapp. I have gone through Ejabberd and Socket.IO Can anyone suggest the best chat server.

Comment: I would suggest you to goto ejabberd.....

Comment: Question about which thing is best -> opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choice is subjective, but ejabberd will have more feature for build a large scale, full-featured chat service.

Note: I am an ejabberd developer.

Comment: I have chosen ejabberd. Now just going through the documentation